# WCF: Matching a specific WS-Security scheme (Signature, Encrypt, UserPass)

Tags: asp.net, wcf, soap, ws-security

I'm trying to match a specific WS-Security specification from a vendor. The following works in SOAP UI, which I am now trying to recreate in C# WCF (targeting .NET 4.7.2 or 4.8):

- Username/Password element
- Timestamp: 9000ms
- Signature (cert A):

  - Sign with certificate
  - Prepend signature element
  - Sign timestamp and username token
- Encryption (cert B):

  - Create encrypted key
  - Encrypt body, timestamp, and username token

Everything I've tried so far seems to encrypt everything in the WS-Security header except for the timestamp.

References followed:

- [WCF - Separate x509 for Signing and Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/how-to-use-separate-x-509-certificates-for-signing-and-encryption)

---

**SOAP UI Setup - Signature:**

[image: SOAPUI-Signature]

**SOAP UI Setup - Encryption:**

[image: SOAPUI-Encryption]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use IClientMessageInspectortor add a header to the message. In the BeforeSendRequest method, you can add a custom header to the outgoing message.Here is a demo:

```
      public class CustomMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        return;
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        MessageHeader header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Testreply", "http://Test", "Test");
        request.Headers.Add(header);
        return null;
    }
}
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface)]
public class CustContractBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IContractBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        return;
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(new CustomMessageInspector());
    }
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
    {
        return;
    }

    public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Add CustContractBehaviorAttribute to apply it:

[image]

Comment: This is not what I'm trying to accomplish; I need to use WCF to configure the security and encryption to match what SOAPUI is doing.

Comment: Do you want to add some safety headers? Like Timestamp and usernameToken.

Comment: As stated, the timestamp provided by WCF is not being encrypted; I can try adding this custom header but will it be able to partake in the encryption/signing process?

Comment: You can use AesCryptoServiceProvider to encrypt the timestamp, you can refer to this link: https://forums.asp.net/t/1787025.aspx?implementing+AES+256+encryption+for+a+WCF+service+with+a+timestamp+value